# Moving a separate glyph in TextField/TextBlock/TextLine

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, text, actionscript

I want to make an RPG-like animation with text, like waving, shaking, etc. So I need to move separate glyphs in in text container. I looked up in Adobe documentation, but didn't find myself any information about accessing separate glyph graphics, to change it's position/scale/whatever.

Is it possible? Or the only way to do it is to draw glyphs separately from text field to BitmapData and do the whole thing by myself?

Comment: Yeah by yourself or use a paid for version of green sock.  They have a tween library that dies exactly what you are talking about. But it is t included in their free version. It might not even be included in their normal version. You may have to buy the highest level if I recall correctly.

Comment: Either use bitmapdata as said or put each letter in its own sprite container then animate / transform the specific container(s)...

Comment: in additional (to above comments), i have to say that you  can using filters too, displacementmap or pixel bending which needs to caching TextField as bitmap.